# Web-based scheduling system which allows booking for custom durations

Tags: api, web

I want to make a website that offers a booking system with custom reservation times. My client wants to provide a conference room where customers can book them for a desired time slot.

Website builders like Squarespace or Wix and even API's like Timekit and Calendly only offer fixed durations in their booking system to choose from (e.g. book for 5h at 9 for 250$) but I want the customer to decide how long he/she stays (e.g. book from 11 to 14.30 for some price).

Is there a simple solution like another Website builder or a simple API with an embeddable scheduler that is both reliable and secure?